# How to print a table with mean and standard error

Tags: r, datatable, statistics, mean

I'm trying reporting a table complete with descriptive statistics from a dataset I'm working on, including the mean, the standard error in brackets and the grouping variable too. The dataset is the following one (I here report it thanks to the dput function).

```
> dput(dati)
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27), 
    sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), d8 = c(21, 
    21, NA, 23.5, 21.5, 20, 21.5, 23, NA, 16.5, 24.5, 26, 21.5, 
    23, 25.5, 20, 24.5, 22, 24, 23, 27.5, 23, 21.5, 17, 22.5, 
    23, 22), d10 = c(20, 21.5, 24, 24.5, 23, 21, 22.5, 23, 21, 
    19, 25, 25, 22.5, 22.5, 27.5, 23.5, 25.5, 22, 21.5, 20.5, 
    28, 23, 23.5, 24.5, 25.5, 24.5, 21.5), d12 = c(21.5, 24, 
    NA, 25, 22.5, 21, 23, 23.5, NA, 19, 28, 29, 23, NA, 26.5, 
    22.5, 27, 24.5, 24.5, 31, 31, 23.5, 24, 26, 25.5, 26, 23.5
    ), d14 = c(23, 25.5, 26, 26.5, 23.5, 22.5, 25, 24, 21.5, 
    19.5, 28, 31, 26.5, 27.5, 27, 26, 28.5, 26.5, 25.5, 26, 31.5, 
    25, 28, 29.5, 26, 30, 25)), row.names = c(NA, -27L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), sex = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), d8 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), d10 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), d12 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), d14 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I was able to draw the right code generated automatically from the Rcmdr library, although it turns back a table with mean and standard deviations

```
#####Summary table of sample characteristics#####
CatTable <- CreateCatTable(vars = c("sex"), strata="sex", data=dati_locf)
matCatTable <- print(CatTable, printToggle = FALSE, showAllLevels = TRUE, 
  exact=c("sex"), smd = FALSE)
matCatTable <- matCatTable[,colnames(matCatTable)!="test"]
matCatTable <- cbind(Factor=row.names(matCatTable), matCatTable)
ContTable <- CreateContTable(vars = c("d8", "d10", "d12", "d14"), 
  strata="sex", data=dati_locf)
matContTable <- print(ContTable, printToggle = FALSE, explain = FALSE, smd 
  = FALSE)
matContTable <- matContTable[,colnames(matContTable)!="test"]
matContTable <- cbind(level="", matContTable)
matContTable <- cbind(Factor=row.names(matContTable), matContTable)
FinalTable <- as.matrix(matCatTable)
tempStrata <- attributes(FinalTable)[[2]][2]
FinalTable <- rbind(FinalTable, matContTable)
attributes(FinalTable) <- c(list(dim=attributes(FinalTable)[[1]]), 
  list(dimnames=c(attributes(FinalTable)[[2]][1], tempStrata)))
colnames(FinalTable)[2] <- "Group"
colnames(FinalTable)[colnames(FinalTable)=="p"] <- "p.value"
row0 <- colnames(FinalTable)
row1 <- FinalTable[1,]
row1 <- matrix(row1, nrow=1)
colnames(row1) <- row0
FinalTable <- FinalTable[which(rownames(FinalTable)!="n"),]
FinalTable <- rbind(n=row1, FinalTable)
FinalTable <- rbind(row0, FinalTable)
row0 <- rep("", length(colnames(FinalTable)))
row0[3] <- "sex"
FinalTable <- rbind(row0, FinalTable)
finaltable_dataframe_print(FinalTable)
write.table(FinalTable, "clipboard", sep = "    ", row.names = FALSE, 
  col.names=FALSE)
```

How could I obtain an item like that, just with the standard error in place of the standard deviation?

Comment: Where are those functions from (CreateCatTable, etc.), are they from package tableone?

Comment: Exactly, they are from that package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your own se function, then add it to the CreateContTable arguments. Here's one way:

```
se = function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(x)))

ContTable <- CreateContTable(
vars = c("d8", "d10", "d12", "d14")
,strata="sex"
,data=dati_locf
,funcAdditional = list(se=se)
)

summary(ContTable) #Shows you se is included in output
```

Comment: It works very great. Thanks for helping. May you have any clue about reshaping the code I've posted above in order to print a table with just mean and standard error aside in brackets? I've tried replacing the code you've suggested in place of the first line command but it keeps on printing the same table than before.

Comment: ContTable is a list with 2 elements, M and F. Each element is a matrix that includes n, mean, se as columns. You'd have to put together thr output you like using some string functions like paste.